# How to select multiple ids that have a certain class in CSS

Tags: css

All I want to do is select multiple elements and with a certain class so that I don't have redundancy in my CSS file

```
 #resp36, #physicalResp36, #nonResp36, #physicalNonResp36 .fieldStateError {
        border: 1px solid #d6dbdc!important;
 }
```

But the last element does not get the stlye while the others do. And I am not certain why that is happening.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this "Certain Class", the same class throughout?

Comment: sounds like you want to remove the space, ie. `#physicalNonResp36.fieldStateError`

Comment: The element with ID "physicalNonResp36" has the class "fieldStateError" right?

Comment: If all the elements need to have the class in order to get the style, add the .class to each of the selectors. Not just the last one.

Comment: Yes they all posses that class

Comment: then why not just style that class? or if there are other items with that class that need a different style, why not add another class and style that, eg: give the ones that need this border a class of `border` and then use `.border.fieldStateError`.  The way you are doing it seems a bit unwieldy and will become unmaintainable very quickly if you need to add the id for each error that requires a border

Answer (score 4):

Spaces in a selector cause looking for child elements. You can select an element with multiple conditions by simply putting all selectors right behind each other:

```
#resp36.fieldStateError,
#physicalResp36.fieldStateError,
#nonResp36.fieldStateError,
#physicalNonResp36.fieldStateError {
    border: 1px solid #d6dbdc !important;
}
```

Note that this is pretty much one of the most redundant things you could do in CSS, as classes are meant to unify such declarations into a single selector. Unless you were slinging the `.fieldStateError` class around, this should have the same effect as the code above:

```
.fieldStateError {
    border: 1px solid #d6dbdc !important;
}
```

Comment: in my case i have:  id="Ribbon.ListItem.Manage.ManagePermissions-Medium", how can i get the element by css !!

Answer (score 0):

you do not have a comma before ".fieldStateError".

Example:

```
     #resp36, #physicalResp36, #nonResp36, #physicalNonResp36, .fieldStateError {
        border: 1px solid #d6dbdc!important;
 }
```

or remove the gap (`<div id="#physicalNonResp36" class="fieldStateError">`)

```
#resp36, #physicalResp36, #nonResp36, #physicalNonResp36.fieldStateError {
        border: 1px solid #d6dbdc!important;
 }
```

Comment: This will make it apply to all of those ids, plus all any that has the class "fieldStateError", OP wants it to be applied only when you do have thoses ids plus the class associated to it. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all your elements have that class, you only need to use the class selector.

If you wanted to select the last id that also has that class, remove the space between class and id, because you are asking for a son of that id with that class.